# Verilog coding guidance for operations in different cycles

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, rtl

I want to do 3 operations in 3 different clock cycles: data in, addition and multiplication, and then repeat. Can anyone give me a Verilog template to implement the above? Something like this pseudocode:

```
always @(posedge 1st clk or negedge rst)
    if (~rst)
        a <= 0;
    else
        a <= data_in;

always @(posedge 2nd clk or negedge rst)
    if (~rst)
        b <= 0;
    else
        b <= a + c;

always @(posedge 3rd clk or negedge rst)
    if (~rst)
        d <= 0;
    else
        d <= a * b;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a counter to decide when to do your 3 operations.  Something like the following:

```
reg [1:0] count;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
    if (~rst)
        count <= 0;
    else if (count == 2)
        count <= 0;
    else
        count <= count + 1;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
    if (~rst)
        a <= 0;
    else if (count == 0)
        a <= data_in;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
    if (~rst)
        b <= 0;
    else if (count == 1)
        b <= a + c;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
    if (~rst)
        d <= 0;
    else if (count == 2)
        d <= a * b;
```

The counter will have this sequence: 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, etc.

When the count is 0, assign the data to `a`.  On the next clock cycle, when count is 1, do the addition, etc.